# JSON parsing with JsonResult and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

**Environment:** ASP.net MVC:

Given anonymous structure as such:

```
var test = new {
  name = "me",
  age = "100"
};
```

that then gets parsed as

```
result = Json(test)
data = result.Data // Comes back with { name = "me", age = "100" }
```

Which then gets successfully passed into a JS function, how do I go about using that as a JSON object, so that I can do something like

```
function(data) // Where data = { name = "me", age = "100" } or similar
{
  var name = data.name // "me"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var object = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

then you should be able to do object.name.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, even when using eval(data) - it says "me" is undefined and the VS debugger shows eval breaking on { name = me, age = 100 }, without the quotes.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON isn't { "name": "me", "age": 100 }?

Comment: No. I think part of the issue is with result = Json(test).

Comment: Actually. Post what the response is from the server(action). So we can see the Json string?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid, it should be

```
{
    "name" : "me",
    "age"  : "100"
}
```

And `new {..}` doesn't do anything meaningful -- the object literal is alone sufficient.